# Use Photoshop JavaScript to Execute System Command Line Prompt

Tags: windows, command-prompt, command-line-interface, photoshop-script

I'm using Photoshop to automate processing images using action sets. I have added javascript to one of my action sets. I want to issue a windows command line prompt using the javascript. Is this possible? Is there some type of `system_exec()` function for doing this?

Edit: Here's an easy test

```
app.system("mshta javascript:alert(\"Hello World\");close();");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
app.system("some Windows command")
```

E.g.

```
app.system("echo hi > C:\hi.txt")
```