# Make photoshop run system command through javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I have a line of code as below

```
app.system("cmd.exe python D:\project\PStest.py");
```

This is to run a python script from within photoshop. The similar question is asked here already and I followed the same 
     [Use Photoshop JavaScript to Execute System Command Line Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661822/use-photoshop-javascript-to-execute-system-command-line-prompt)

When I execute the above code I get an error as

```
Error 24: app.system is not a function.
```

Answer (score 1):

I got that error while in ExtendedScript tool with the wrong environement.

I never manadge to get the app.system() command to work with:

```
#target photoshop
app.system( "python  C:\ps_test.py");
```

the cmd window popup and close right away, nothing happens.
If you know the right way to write it.

A workaround I found as a beginner.

```
#target photoshop
var bat = new File("C:/ps_test.bat");
bat.execute();
```

Comment: did you try system("python xxx") ? seems like the system by itself works.