# Getting width and height of image without need of opening it in PS - CS6 script

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I strugled to search the answer in documentation ([1](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/scripting/Photoshop-CS6-JavaScript-Ref.pdf), [2](https://github.com/1179432578/psd-tool/blob/master/JavaScript%20Tools%20Guide%20CS6.pdf)) but I couldn't find anyone.
Consider that we have array of files from certain folder located in hard drive. We want to filter these files in this array depending on dimensions of its files.
That means, filter images which both sides (width or height) are **higher** than some value **and** **lower** than some value at the same time.
 Of course we can open each file in PS as `Document` and check each one by property `app.activeDocument.width` or `app.activeDocument.height` and choose highest one and match it. But it is **extremely inefficient**, especially when we have hundreds of files but only few of them meet conditions.

So my question is:
 Is there any possibility to check `width` and `height` without opening the image?
If this is possible to do without a need of installing 3rd party software, it's great.
If not, it would be great that you don't have to install it manually (some stand alone version).
 Even when condition above are not met, it's better any solution than no one.

code:

```
var sourceFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Select folder with files to process");

var LowestValueOfSides = 50; // Any arbitrary value

var HighestValueOfSides = 100; // Any arbitrary value

var FilesToProcess = getFilesToProcess(sourceFolder, LowestValueOfSides, HighestValueOfSides);

alert(FilesToProcess);

function getFilesToProcess(sourceFolder, LowestValueOfSides, HighestValueOfSides) {

    sourceFilesUnfiltered = sourceFolder.getFiles();
    var properFilesExtPSfiles = /.(jpg|tif|psd|bmp|gif|png)$/;

    var sourceFilesFilteredPSD = filteringSourceFilesByExtensions(sourceFilesUnfiltered, properFilesExtPSfiles);

    var sourceFilesFilteredByRes = filteringSourceFilesByRes(sourceFilesFilteredPSD, LowestValueOfSides, HighestValueOfSides);

    return sourceFilesFilteredByRes;
}

function filteringSourceFilesByExtensions(sourceFilesUnfiltered, properFilesExtPSfiles) {

    var sourceFilesFiltered = new Array;

    for (var i = 0; i < sourceFilesUnfiltered.length; i++) { 
        if (sourceFilesUnfiltered[i] instanceof File) {

            var sourceFilePathString = sourceFilesUnfiltered[i].toString();

            var sourceFileToMatch = decodeURIComponent(sourceFilePathString);

            if (sourceFileToMatch.match(properFilesExtPSfiles)) {// decodeURIComponent(), to avoid problem when you have special signs in source files

                sourceFilesFiltered.push( File(sourceFilePathString) );
            } 
        } 
    }

    return sourceFilesFiltered;
}

function filteringSourceFilesByRes(sourceFilesFilteredPSD, LowestValueOfSides, HighestValueOfSides) {

    var sourceFilesFilteredByRes = new Array;

    for (var i = 0; i < sourceFilesFilteredPSD.length; i++) {

        var longestSide = getLongestSideValue(sourceFilesFilteredPSD[i]); //   <====== this is function which I have problem

        if ( (longestSide >= LowestValueOfSides) && (longestSide <= HighestValueOfSides)) {
            sourceFilesFilteredByRes.push(sourceFilesFilteredPSD[i]);
        }
    }

    return sourceFilesFilteredByRes;
}

function getLongestSideValue(File) { //   <====== this is function which I have problem

    var FileWidth // <===== I need this value
    var FileHeight // <===== I need this value

    var longestSideValue = Math.max(FileWidth, FileHeight);

    return longestSideValue;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried actualHeight/actualWidth? See [this post](https://ricardomoinhos.com/photoshop-scripting/)

Comment: actualWidth and actualHeight in the above post are just local variables that refer to an openend document not a generic property. @Lukkar I'm afraid the only option is to programatically open the file using open(file) , get it's width using .width.value and close it afterwards.

Comment: @obscure please post an answer if you have one

Comment: @RachelGallen sadly there is none other than the solution Lukkar has already mentioned in his question.

Comment: @RachelGallen Yes this solution is one which I rejected at the beginning. It works but it it is inefficient. Unfortunately solution which /obscure mentioned is exactly from my question.

Comment: True. Adobe just didn't think of this use-case. The File class holds some properties but of course not the physical dimensions.

Comment: I haven't tried but maybe something from [this post](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/use-the-ps-script-to-get-the-exif-of-the-image-without-opening-it-in-photoshop/td-p/9968618?page=1) will work

Comment: @obscure - _"Adobe just didn't think of this use-case."_ that's not entirely true. See [Scripting Access to XMP Metadata](https://estk.aenhancers.com/10%20-%20Scripting%20Access%20to%20XMP%20Metadata/index.html). There may be _some_ cases whereby the _"option is to programmatically open the file using open(file)"_, (particularly for formats such as `.png`, `bmp` and `.gif` if they haven't been processed via an Adobe application), however I disagree that it's the _"only option"_. Lukkar may try getting dimensions via the XMP packet, if the meta doesn't exist then revert to using `open(file)`.

Comment: @RobC I'm aware of the metadata but it's no standard for it to include the file dimensions - some filetypes even don't have metadata - that's why I said it's the only option because it's the only reliable.

Comment: @obscure - sure that's why I said _"if the meta doesn't exist then revert to using open(file)"_.

Comment: @obscure _(particularly for formats such as .png, bmp and .gif if they haven't been processed via an Adobe application)_ Exactly. In my case these ones are which XMP can't be read . Even when they were created by PS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what sort of answer you are looking for because you seem to want to write Javascript but you don't want Photoshop to open your images, so I wanted to advise that you can use **ImageMagick** to get the width and height of all your JPEG/PNG images easily enough in Terminal (Command Prompt) like this:

```
magick identify -format "%hx%w - %f\n" *.jpg *.png
1936x2592 - iphone.jpg
100x100 - lime.jpg
600x600 - out.jpg
400x400 - paddington.jpg
100x100 - red.jpg
1936x2592 - result-fft.jpg
50x50 - result.jpg
178x178 - 1.png
178x178 - 2.png
```

Note that PSD and TIFF files often have multiple layers, so you may want to add the layer number in there for those types:

```
magick identify -format "%hx%w - %f[%s]\n" *psd *tif
768x1024 - a.psd[0]
768x1024 - a.psd[1]
248x1280 - a.tif[0]
```

Comment: Is it possible to invoke Terminal (Command Prompt) and pass arguments to it, in Adobe's ExtendedScript?

Comment: Do you mean this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26662083/2836621

Comment: It works but.... in my case 'app.system("some Windows command")' doesn't work.
You have to create bat file, which later you execute [link]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029039/make-photoshop-run-system-command-through-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: `var bat = new File("~/Documents/ps_test.bat");`
`bat.open('w');`
`bat.writeln('magick identify -format "%%hx%%w - %%f\\n" "D:\\some path\\file.png">"D:\\some path\\results.txt"');`
`bat.writeln("pause");`
`bat.close();`
`bat.execute();`

Comment: Additional information about **escape** characters for anyone who wants to create own **bat** file in **jsx**:
[JavaScript](https://www.freeformatter.com/javascript-escape.html),
[bat](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)